# I am facing error 404 in OpenCart when I save changes in Admin

Tags: php, .htaccess, opencart

I am facing strange problem this is my Open cart theme. When I try to save any changes in my admin panel it redirects me to 404 page. Is it any issues in my .htaccess I mentioned it below I am facing strange problem this is my Open cart theme.

When I try to save any changes in my admin panel it redirects me to 404 page. Is it any issues in my `.htaccess` I mentioned it below

```
     # 1.To use URL Alias you need to be running apache with mod_rewrite enabled. 



        # 2. In your opencart directory rename htaccess.txt to .htaccess.



        # For any support issues please visit: http://www.opencart.com



        Options +FollowSymlinks



        # Prevent Directoy listing 

        Options -Indexes



        # Prevent Direct Access to files

        <FilesMatch "\.(tpl|ini|log)">

         Order deny,allow

         Deny from all

        </FilesMatch>



        # SEO URL Settings

        RewriteEngine On

        # If your opencart installation does not run on the main web folder make sure you folder it does run in ie. / becomes /shop/ 



        RewriteBase /

        RewriteRule ^sitemap.xml$ index.php?route=feed/google_sitemap [L]

        RewriteRule ^googlebase.xml$ index.php?route=feed/google_base [L]

        RewriteRule ^download/(.*) /index.php?route=error/not_found [L]

        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*\.(ico|gif|jpg|jpeg|png|js|css)

        RewriteRule ^([^?]*) index.php?_route_=$1 [L,QSA]



        ### Additional Settings that may need to be enabled for some servers 

        ### Uncomment the commands by removing the # sign in front of it.

        ### If you get an "Internal Server Error 500" after enabling any of the following settings, restore the # as this means your host doesn't allow that.



        # 1. If your cart only allows you to add one item at a time, it is possible register_globals is on. This may work to disable it:

        # php_flag register_globals off



        # 2. If your cart has magic quotes enabled, This may work to disable it:

        # php_flag magic_quotes_gpc Off



        # 3. Set max upload file size. Most hosts will limit this and not allow it to be overridden but you can try

        # php_value upload_max_filesize 999M



        # 4. set max post size. uncomment this line if you have a lot of product options or are getting errors where forms are not saving all fields

        # php_value post_max_size 999M



        # 5. set max time script can take. uncomment this line if you have a lot of product options or are getting errors where forms are not saving all fields

        # php_value max_execution_time 200



        # 6. set max time for input to be recieved. Uncomment this line if you have a lot of product options or are getting errors where forms are not saving all fields

        # php_value max_input_time 200



        # 7. disable open_basedir limitations

        # php_admin_value open_basedir none
```

Comment: Any One here to resolve it as soon as possible :(

Comment: Have you even changed anything from the `.htaccess` file anyway? Have you tried downloading a fresh copy of `.htaccess` from a new Opencart install?

Answer (score 0):

- check the admin folder permissions
- check that 'config.php' in the admin folder is setup correctly (data base name, user, password...)